# Circular dependency causing ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: python, django, model, circular-dependency

This is the first time I have encountered this. Maybe it's due to bad design. Anyway, I don't know how to fix it. Here are the models that are not playing nicely:

**talk/models.py**

```
from agencies.models import UserProfile
class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    source = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='source')
    dest = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='dest')

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

**agencies/models.py**

```
# from talk.models import Message
```

When I uncomment that it says `ImportError: cannot import name UserProfile`. I really want it though so I can add this property to my UserProfile class...

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
        # ...
        @property
        def unseen_messages_from(self):
            pass # :(
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: So you have Message class that uses UserProfile and you want to have UserProfile that uses Message class, is that right?

Comment: Yes, I do. Is this impossible?

Comment: The messaging goes 1:M. So for that 1, I want to see m.unseen_messages_from for associated m. If that makes any sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django foreign keys allow you to specify models as strings to avoid import issues. In your case you could do:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    source = models.ForeignKey('<appname>.UserProfile', related_name='source')
    dest = models.ForeignKey('<appname>.UserProfile', related_name='dest')

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

ie, you can remove the import all together.

Ref, [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

Comment: <appname> = agencies?

Comment: @broinjc, it would be the app under which the `UserProfile` model is.

Comment: Thank you this worked great. And thanks for the ref to the docs. Even more helpful +1

Comment: This was driving me nuts.  This question has been asked and answered with solutions that did not work.  You saved me a big headache.  Thank you.